# why do android rotation sensor events change when phone hasnt rotated?

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, virtual-reality

I'm using `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` and changing it to a matrix with `getRotationMatrixFromVector`.

With this rotation matrix, I multiple my view.

Basically I want to change what is shown on the phone, based on whether I'm looking left, up, down, right, etc. Ie a basic VR type app.

However I'm finding it extremely odd that when I leave my phone on my table, in other words, it is flat and not moving, there is about 15-20 seconds where the "rotation matrix settles down" and stops rotating.

Why does this initial "erroneous rotation readings" occur?

And is there a way around this? If not, what is the proper way to calculate rotation of the phone? Am I suppose to use the GYROSCOPE sensor?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check how much the rotation matrix changes when you lay it on the table? I wouldn't be surprised if there was some minor noise in the readings.

Comment: It is quite significant. I see the object turn a full 90 degrees. When I say 'lay it on the table', I mean it starts off on the table and doesn't move. However the initial readings are a full 90 degrees different after 30 seconds. That seems very odd to me...